# Convolutions of (m)-associahedra and (m)-noncrossing partition polynomials--combinatorial proofs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, polynomials, discrete-geometry

I'm looking for combinatorial proofs of the convolutional identity **COP** below and its specializations I) and II).

(Edit 6/2/2023: A combinatorial proof is sketched in a blog post by Mike Spivey of a Rothe-Hagen generalized Chu-Vandermonde convolution identity that encompasses specialization I--"[Combinatorial Proofs of Two Hagen-Rothe Identities in Concrete Mathematics](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/combinatorial-proofs-of-two-hagen-rothe-identities-in-concrete-mathematics/)".)

For $m$ any integer, the sets $[A^{(m)}]$ of (m)-associahedra partition polynomials (ParPs) $A_n^{(m)}(u_1,...,u_n)$ and the sets $[N^{(m)}]$ of (m)-noncrossing partitions / (m)-refined Narayana / (m)-parking function ParPs $N_n^{(m)}(u_1,...,u_2)$ are characterized in my pdf "[As Above, So Below: (m)-associahedra and (m)-noncrossing partitions polynomials, Section 1](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2023/05/11/as-above-so-below-m-associahedra-and-m-noncrossing-partitions-polynomials/)" at my mini-arXiv with explicit multinomial expressions for the coefficients of the monomials of the ParPs.

Given $[A^{(1)}]=[A]$, the refined Euler characteristic partition polynomials, or signed, refined face polynomials, of the convex associahedra polytopes and $[N^{(1)}]= [N]$, the associated signed, refined h-polynomials (or given one of these and the reciprocal ParPs $[A^{(0)}] =[R]$, refined binomial, or Pascal, ParPs for multiplicative inversion of power series / o.g.f.s), the other sets are determined by **the core identity**

$$[A^{(m)}] = [N^{(m)}][R] = [N]^m[R],$$

denoting substitution of $R_k(u_1,...,u_k)$ for the indeterminate $u_k$ of $N^{(m)}_n(u_1,...,u_n)$ for $1  \leq k \leq n.$ The $[N]^m$ are iterated self-substitutions of $[N]$ into itself with $[N]^{-1}= [N^{(-1)}]$, the inverse to $[N]$ under substitution.

It follows from their relations to compositional inversion of power and Laurent series that $[A^{(m)}]$ are involutive, so

$$ [A^{(m)}] = [A^{(m)}]^{-1} = ([N^{(m)}][R])^{-1} =[R] [N]^{-m}.$$

An equivalent rep of this identity with, e.g., $A^{(m)}(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} A_n^{(m)}(u_1,...,u_n) x^n$

is **the reciprocal identity**

$$A^{(m)}(x) = \frac{1}{N^{(-m)}(x)},$$

or

$$1 = A^{(m)}(x) N^{(-m)}(x).$$

The Cauchy convolution identity applies to give the

**convolution identity of the partition polynomials (COP)**:

$$\delta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{(m)}(u_1,...,u_n)N_{n-k}^{(-m)}(u_1,...,u_n).$$

Specializations give identities among the (m)-Fuss-Catalan and (m)-Fuss-Narayana number sequences. Be aware that in the literature the names are often interchanged, and, in fact, the two sets are shifted versions of each other with (m)-Fuss-Catalan equal to (m+1)-Fuss-Narayana numbers (absolute values). I define them in terms of the diagonal numbers, or coefficients of the n'th order monomials, of the ParPs with $(-1)^n DA_n^{(m)} =  DN_n^{(m+1)}$. (See explicit formulas for these sequences below.)

(To add to potential conflation, the (-1)-Fuss-Catalan numbers are often called the positive Catalan numbers by cluster theorists for geometric reasons.)

**Specializations / reductions:**

**I)** For **diagonal coefficients**, the (m)-Fuss-Catalan and (m)-Fuss-Narayana numbers:

$\delta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{(m)}(t,0,...,0)N_{n-k}^{(-m)}(t,0,...,0) = t^n \sum_{k=0}^n DA_k^{(m)}DN_{n-k}^{(-m)},$

or

$\delta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n DA_k^{(m)}DN_{n-k}^{(-m)} = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k DA_k^{(m)}DA_{n-k}^{(-m-1)} = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k DN_k^{(m+1)} DN_{n-k}^{(-m)} .$

**II)** For the **associated single-variable polynomials**:

$\delta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{(m)}(t,t,...,t)N_{n-k}^{(-m)}(t,t,...,t)= \sum_{k=0}^n TA_k^{(m)}(t)TN_{n-k}^{(-m)}(t) .$

**III)** **Sums of coefficients** of the polynomials give I) again, but provide a different avenue of interpretation:

$\delta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{(m)}(1,1,...,1)N_{n-k}^{(-m)}(1,1,...,1) =\sum_{k=0}^n DN_k^{(m)}DA^{(-m)}_{n-k} . $

---

**Explicit expressions for the Fuss-Catalan / Fuss-Narayana numbers**

Initially,

$DA_0^{(m)} = DN_0^{(m)}= DN_1^{(m)} = -DA_1^{(m)} = 1$ for all integer $m$.

For $n > 1$ evaluate the following expressions with positively signed $m$ for $m \geq 0$ and other expressions otherwise;

$DN_n^{(m)} = \frac{1}{mn+1} \binom{mn+1}{n} = (-1)^n \frac{1}{mn+1} \binom{(-m+1)n-2}{n}$

$ = \frac{1}{n} \binom{mn}{n-1} = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n} \binom{(-m+1)n-2}{n-1}$

and

$DA_n^{(m)} =(-1)^n \frac{1}{mn+1} \binom{(m+1)n}{n} = \frac{1}{mn+1} \binom{-mn-1}{n}$

$ = (-1)^n  \frac{1}{n} \binom{(m+1)n}{n-1} = -\frac{1}{n} \binom{-mn-2}{n-1} .$

---

**Spot checks / illustrations**:

**For $m=1$,**

$\delta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{(1)}(u_1,0,...,0)N_{n-k}^{(-1)}(u_1,0,...,0) = \sum_{k=0}^n DA_k^{(1)}DN_{n-k}^{(-1)}$

Diagonal monomials of  $[A^{(1)}]$ are $(1,-1u_1,2u_1^2,-5u_1^3, 14u_1^4,...)$, signed Catalans.

Diagonal monomials of $[N^{(-1)}]$ are $(1,1u_1,-1u_1^2,2u_1^3, -5u_1^4, 14u_1^5,...)$, shifted, signed Catalans.

$DA(t) = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+4t}}{2t} = 1 - t + 2 t^2 - 5 t^3 + 14 t^4 - 42 t^5 + \cdots$,

and

$DN^{(-1)}(t) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+4t}}{2} = 1 + t - t^2 + 2 t^3 - 5 t^4 + 14 t^5 +\cdots,$

so

$DA(t)DN^{(-1)}(t) = 1.$

**For $m=-1$,**

$\delta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{(-1)}(u_1,0,...,0)N_{n-k}^{(1)}(u_1,0,...,0) = \sum_{k=0}^n DA_k^{(-1)}DN_{n-k}^{(1)}$

Diagonal monomials of  $A^{(-1)}]$ are $(1,-u_1,0,0,0,...)$ with associated o.g.f. $1-t$.

Diagonal monomials of $[N^{(1)}]$ are $(1,u_1,u_1^2,...)$ with associated o.g.f. $1/(1-t)$.

For $n >1$

$\sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{(-1)}(1,0,...,0) \cdot 1 = \sum_{k=0}^n DA_k^{(-1)} \cdot 1 = 1-1 = 0.$

**For $m=0$,**

Diagonal monomials of  $[A^{(0)}] = [R]$ are $(1,-1u_1,1u_1^2,-1u_1^3, 1u_1^4,...)$ with associated o.g.f. $\frac{1}{1+t}.$

Diagonal monomials of $[N^{(0)}] = [I]$, the identity under substitution, are $(1,u_1,0,...)$ with associated o.g.f. $1+t$.

For $n \geq 0$,

$\sum_{k=0}^n DA^{(0)}_{n-k}  \cdot DN_k^{(0)} = \delta_n .$

**For $m= 2$**,

convolution for $n=4$:

$[DA^{(2)}] = (1,-1,3,-12,55,...) = $ signed OEIS [A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764),

$[DN^{(-2)}] = (1,1,-2,7,-30,...) = $ signed (1,[A006013](https://oeis.org/A006013)).

$\sum_{0}^4 DA_k^{(2)}DN_{n-k}^{(-2)} = (1)(-30)+(-1)(7)+(3)(-2)+ (-12)(1) +(55) (1) = 0 $.

---

**Edit 6/3/2023:**

I think the gist of a proof can be found in weaving together Theorem I of “[Some convolution series identities](https://dspace.library.uvic.ca/handle/1828/1765)” by Raina and Srivastava for a very general convolution identity for pairs of series with discussion of the Lagrange inversion formula 2.1.2 (pg. 2) and 4.2.1 (pg. 23) in "[Lagrange inversion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05988.pdf)" by Gessel. The function $R$ in Gessel corresponds to $x/f^{(-1)}(x)$ in his notation in Theorem 2.1.1, so, to $N^{(-m)}(x)$ here. See also identity (2) on p. 2 of "[Lagrange inversion for species](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Egessel/homepage/papers/lagrange-species.pdf)" by Gessel and Labelle and Lemma 5.6.4 on pg. 68 of the thesis “[Lattice path enumeration and factorization](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Egessel/homepage/students/lemusthesis.pdf)” by Vidales.  Mohanty in his book Lattice Path Counting and Applications discusses more specialized convolution identities surrounding eqns. 6.1 and 6.2 on pg. 166 and 6.6 on pg. 168.